# Access Restricted for API Only Users

Tags: api, single-sign-on, authorization

When I attempt to login using SSO, I get prompted for two factor authentication and when I enter the 2fa code, I am greeted with a message that says "Access Restricted for API Only Users - You’re successfully registered for two-factor authentication, and can no longer access the UI. Close this window to continue."

[image]

However, I have confirmed that am not an API only user. I have cleared my cache and cookies and this still happens. I see the [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_auth_2fa_api_user_access.htm) which describe the page, but I don't understand why I am seeing that error.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How have you confirmed you're not an API only user

Comment: Another system admin viewed my user record.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have an additional Permission Set that added this permission? I've never seen this happen unless the user really was an Api Only user for some reason.

Comment: I have no permission sets assigned to me. I really am stumped on this one....

Answer (score 4):

Salesforce owned many similar access control method , included "Profile" , "Permission set" , "Permission set Group" , "Public Group" ...

To escape from "**Access Restricted for API Only Users**" login error message , you need to ensure "**Api Only User**" option is uncheck ( check below screenshot) by validate all above mentioned access control method.

In my case , that option was enable on "Profile" level so i use those steps fix the error.
**Setup > Quick find textbox key in "Profile" > select and edit impacted profile by uncheck "Api Only User" option**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out,

While I did not have any permission set assignments, I did have a permission set group assignment which contained a permission set with the "API Only" user permission.

I feel silly for not having checked this earlier but I am glad to have figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue of being stuck on the error page after creating an Integration User and having no way to logout of Salesforce. I overcame this by opening an incognito browser, logged in as a System Admin again and reset the password for the Integration User. Closed my main browser and re-opened again to get the login screen where I could login as the System Admin again.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't logout and tried Mary's method, but it didn't work.
So I went to Setup | Management and found my API user and deleted the session. That did work for me.