# Access Restricted to API Only Users

Tags: api, two-factor-authentication

I am a sys admin and trying to change password of my api only user.As soon as I go thru all the steps of changing the password for api user, i get the below message.The API only user does not have permissions set assigned to it nor does it have any session settings(no high assurance). The profile attached to user was cloned as a system administrator. Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: From your writing i suspect the cloned profile has since been modified; check the profiles system permissions, maybe its set to api only!

Answer (score 0):

Check if "[API Only](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_auth_2fa_api_user_access.htm)" user permission is enabled under 'Administrative Permissions' on Profile or Permission Sets/Permission Set Groups.

When you enable the API User checkbox it restricts the permission of UI based login.  Check more details of API Only [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000331470&type=1&mode=1).

Thanks

Comment: I understand that part..I am not sure its trying to register the  user with multi-factor authentication, even though there's not permission sett assigned to the user

Comment: Can you check on profile? Similar issue (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/315767/access-restricted-for-api-only-users)